# Why updating existing tables by Entity Framework Tool ALWAYS cause errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Adding new tables by **right click on mouse in diagram -> Update Model from Database** succeeds.

BUT, updating existing tables fails. I recieve this error:

```
Error 5: The element 'Principal' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'PropertyRef' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'.
```

To updated existing tables I do:

1. delete them from edmx
2. **right click on mouse -> Update Model from Database** and checking those tables

Comment: We don't see your entities and we don't know what changes do you want to push so we cannot answer the question. It says that probably some entity doesn't have property reference in its entity key.

Comment: I think you have to install the last service pack to resolve this